# Two differents OnClick on two divs, one over the other

Tags: javascript, onclick, html

I have two divs, a big one and a smaller over the other, each div has its own OnClick method. The problem I have is when I clicked the smaller div, the big div's OnClick method is called too.

Who can I avoid that?

Comment: I assume that the elements are nested.

Comment: Can you post a demo?  You can use http://jsbin.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to detect which element was clicked is to analyze target of event ( click event ). I have prepared small example for this case. You can see it in code below.

```
function amIclicked(e, element)
{
    e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(target.id==element.id)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
function oneClick(event, element)
{
    if(amIclicked(event, element))
    {
        alert('One is clicked');
    }
}
function twoClick(event, element)
{
    if(amIclicked(event, element))
    {
        alert('Two is clicked');
    }
}
```

This javascript method can be called before you execute your script

**Example**

```
<style>
#one
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
#two
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 10; 
    margin-top: 20;
}

</style>



<div id="one" onclick="oneClick(event, this);">
    one
    <div id="two" onclick="twoClick(event, this);">
        two
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It finally works mixing answers: 

    event.cancelBubble = true;
    if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();

window.event dont work on Firefox, dont know why

Comment: `window.event` is a non-standard IE property.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is that the `click` event will propagate up the element tree.  Therefore, each element that contains an element that was clicked will also fire a `click` event.

The simplest solution is to add `return false` your handler.

If you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you can call `e.stopPropagation();` otherwise, you'll need to call `e.stopPropagation()` if it exists, and set `event.cancelBubble = true`.

For more information, see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Comment: Thank you for this it works, but there's a minor typo.  You wrote `e.StopPropagation();` but it should be `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 4):

What you're dealing with is event bubbling. Take a look at this article: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html.

Basically, to stop the event from passing to the parent element, you can use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').onClick = function(e) {

    // Do your stuff

    // A cross browser compatible way to stop propagation of the event:
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: The first line of that function could be shortened to `e = e || window.event;`

Comment: It works on Chrome but Firefox said "window.event is undefined"

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a common case of event propagation.  Check out [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) to get the full details on what exactly is happening.  Basically, what you need to do in the smaller div's click handler is this:

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use a javascript library such as www.jquery.com you can easily accomplish what you are trying to do by using the propagation prevention options.

Comment: You don't need to use jQuery or anything else, it's easily done with plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Jquery:

```
$('#outer_div').click(function(event) {
    if(event.target !== event.currentTarget) return;
    alert("outer div is clicked")                   

});
```

This way, if the current target is not the same as the outer div, it will do nothing. You can implement normal functions for the child element.