# onclick the child, avoid the parent function

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I have a `div` and it has a click event. In the `div` there is two link are available with separate click event.

My problem is, while I click the two separate links, the div event only firing not the link event. How can I use this all three events separately?

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

google cancelBubble and cancelPropogation (different methods that do the same thing but needed for firefox and ie)

also see:

[Prevent parent container click event from firing when hyperlink clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997084/prevent-parent-container-click-event-from-firing-when-hyperlink-clicked)

[Two differents OnClick on two divs, one over the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015041/two-differents-onclick-on-two-divs-one-over-the-other)