# onClick event is being caught by the parent element along with the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` and inside it there are some elements.

my parent `div` has a `test()` function by using `onClick`.
in inside parent div there is a `quickView()` function by using `onClick`.

now, when I click on `quickView()` function, `test()` function fired .

```
<div onClick="test();" class="product-inner">
  <h5 class="product-title height-40-px">


    title

    </p>
  </h5>
<hr class="mt8 mb8">
<div class="product-meta">
  <ul class="product-price-list">

    <li><span class="product-save dir-to-right"><strong>7500</strong></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="product-old-price dir-to-right">120,000</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="product-price">%95</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr class="mt0 mb0 mr6 hr-blue">
  <div class="col-md-12 mt10">

    <span class="col-md-6">
      ۹&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-users"></i>
    </span>

    <span class="col-md-6">

      <p class="font-size-12 display-inline">


        zone
        &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>


      </p>

    </span>

  </div>

  <ul class="product-actions-list mt35">

    <li><a data-original-title="add cart" class="btn btn-cart btn-sm popup-text" href="#product-quick-view-add-to-cart" onclick="quickView(18730);" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">cart&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </li><li><a href="" class="btn btn-buy btn-sm">details&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes because whenever you will click inside that parent div. Onclick function of parent div will called.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015041/two-differents-onclick-on-two-divs-one-over-the-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the click event from propagating to the parent. This is how you use it.

**P.S.**  IE supports `e.cancelBubble` instead of `e.stopPropagation()`

```js
function quickView(value, e) {
 if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(value);
}

function test() {
  console.log('test Fired');
}
```

```html
<div onClick="test();" class="product-inner">
  <h5 class="product-title height-40-px">


    title

    </p>
  </h5>
<hr class="mt8 mb8">
<div class="product-meta">
  <ul class="product-price-list">

    <li><span class="product-save dir-to-right"><strong>7500</strong></span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="product-old-price dir-to-right">120,000</span>
    </li>
    <li><span class="product-price">%95</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr class="mt0 mb0 mr6 hr-blue">
  <div class="col-md-12 mt10">

    <span class="col-md-6">
      ۹&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-users"></i>
    </span>

    <span class="col-md-6">

      <p class="font-size-12 display-inline">


        zone
        &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>


      </p>

    </span>

  </div>

  <ul class="product-actions-list mt35">

    <li><a data-original-title="add cart" class="btn btn-cart btn-sm popup-text" href="#product-quick-view-add-to-cart" onclick="quickView(18730, event); " data-effect="mfp-move-from-top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">cart&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </li><li><a href="" class="btn btn-buy btn-sm">details&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your javascript function quickView

Answer (score 1):

Click events are bubbling up from the inner element clicked up to the document root going through all the parents of the clicked element. in order to stop it from propagating  up you should use - event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 1):

That's how event bubbling works. First the click event is triggered on the element that actually was clicked (a.btn.btn-cart in your case) and then it goes upwards and reaches the parent div with test(). You can prevent further event propagation by passing an event to your quickView() function and calling event.stopPropagation(). Then, your HTML should look like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-cart btn-sm popup-text" onclick="quickView(event, 18730);">Cart</a>
```

And your JavaScript function:

```
function quickView(event, number) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(number) // Do some stuff with the passed ID.
}
```